# Why Does the Print$ Share Exist on Some Servers and How Do I Disable It

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I am trying to cleanup my server file shares on all of my Windows Server 2012R2 servers.  About half of my servers have a print$ share even though they do not share any printers (only 2 of my servers legitimately share printers).  Why does this share appear on some but not others and how do I go about disabling it without disabling file sharing as well?  All the solutions I have found involve disabling File and Printer Sharing or disabling all the admin shares (C$, D$, ADMIN$, etc.) - neither of which I want to do.

Comment: "Cleanup" .. why do you want to do that? Administrative shares exist for a reason.

Comment: So what is the reason the print$ administrative share exists for a server that is not hosting/sharing any printers.  The other admin shares I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print share is a base feature of the File and Print services. Windows does not separate those roles, so you get print$ shares on all file servers. If you open "Computer management" on the server, not server manager, there is a share management that may allow you to remove the print share, but this sounds like a bad idea to me. This puts you into non-standard and possible unsupported configuration.

Comment: But all of my file servers have shared folders and only about half have the print$ share?  There must be something that dictates when the print$ share is created.

Comment: If a printer is installed on a server then Windows will create the default hidden `$print` share. Disabling or deleting it doesn't make your servers more secure. Best practice would dictate that you leave the default shares alone.

Answer (score 0):

old post I know , but had this on windows 2016 , and it would not pass a security scans
go to  C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers , right click it , select properties , click the sharing tab, Click Advanced Sharing... , uncheck Share This Folder.